# Correct CacheControl configuration to indicate that a resource representation should NEVER be cached?

Tags: java, http, jax-rs, cache-control

```
private static final CacheControl NEVER;

static
{
    NEVER = new CacheControl();
    NEVER.setNoCache(true);
    NEVER.setMaxAge(-1);
    NEVER.setMustRevalidate(true);
    NEVER.setNoStore(true);
    NEVER.setProxyRevalidate(true);
    NEVER.setSMaxAge(-1);
}
```

I want to configure a `CacheControl` directive that will indicate to all clients and proxies that a resource representation should **NEVER** be cached for any reason. This is what I have found from [my research](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) and reading the JavaDocs.

#### Are there any other settings that I am missing from the above configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration looks fine, however I frequently use `max-age` and `s-maxage` set and `0` in [`Cache-Control`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2) (`-1` should work too).

---

You may also want to add an [`Expires`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.3) header set to `0`, in case the recipient doesn't support `Cache-Control`. From the [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234):

> If a response includes a `Cache-Control` field with the `max-age` directive, a recipient MUST ignore the `Expires` field.  Likewise, if a response includes the `s-maxage` directive, a shared cache recipient MUST ignore the `Expires` field.  In both these cases, the value in `Expires` is only intended for recipients that have not yet implemented the `Cache-Control` field.

---

In JAX-RS, you could use a filter to add such headers to the response and use a name binding annotation to bind the filter to a particular resource method or resource class.

First define the name binding annotation:

```java
@NameBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface NoCache {}
```

Then create a filter to add the headers to the response and annotate it with the `@NoCache` annotation defined above:

```java
@NoCache
@Provider
public class NoCacheFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request, 
                       ContainerResponseContext response) {

        CacheControl cacheControl = new CacheControl();
        cacheControl.setNoStore(true);
        cacheControl.setNoCache(true);
        cacheControl.setMustRevalidate(true);
        cacheControl.setProxyRevalidate(true);
        cacheControl.setMaxAge(0);
        cacheControl.setSMaxAge(0);

        response.getHeaders().add(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, cacheControl.toString());
        response.getHeaders().add(HttpHeaders.EXPIRES, 0);
    }
}
```

Then bind the above defined filter to your endpoints using `@NoCache`:

```java
@Path("/foo")
public class MyResource() {

    @GET
    @NoCache
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String wontCache() {
         ...
    }
}
```

If you want a global filter, you don't need to define the `@NoCache` annotation.

Comment: Why would you set an `Expires` header just to be ignored? [*If there is a Cache-Control header with the "max-age" or "s-maxage" directive in the response, the Expires header is ignored.*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Setting `Expires` to `0` is particularly useful if `Cache-Control` is not implemented by the recipient.